# Difference between cumulative gains chart and cumulative accuracy profile for binary classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-data, accuracy

I am confused about the following:

[Here](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Cumulative_Gain_Chart) I find the definition of cumulative gains chart as the plot of

- x-axis: the rate of predicted positive
- y-axis: true positive rate

It turns out that we can e.g. order by the probability of a positive outcome and plot the corresponding rate of true positives.

On the other hand there is the cumulative accuracy profile (CAP) explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_accuracy_profile) where it is said to be constructed as

> The CAP of a model represents the cumulative number of positive
>   outcomes along the y-axis versus the corresponding cumulative number
>   of a classifying parameter along the x-axis.

Another source for the CAP is ["Measuring the Discriminative Power of Rating Systems"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2793951) by Engelmann, Hayden and Tasche.
Together with the plots I would say that the two concepts are the same. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Cumulative Accuracy profile (CAP) of a credit rating model shows percentage of all borrowers (debtors) on the x-axis and the percentage of defaulters (bad customers) on the y-axis. In marketing analytics, it is called Gain Chart.